# Android : How Do I use blank activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm beginning android programming slowly. I want to blank and white (page of all) theme .So I don't want to see this part of image.

[image http://u1311.hizliresim.com/1h/m/upm9r.png](http://u1311.hizliresim.com/1h/m/upm9r.png)

Comment: You could at least do some research on your own ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest, where the activity is declared, add the "android:theme" as below:

```
<activity
   android:name="yourActivityName"
   android:label="your label"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below line to your manifest application tag. It will remove from all activities and if you want to remove some of activity just copy and paste below code to activity tag.

**android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this in your Activity

```
//Delete title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your main activity:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, in the `activity` tag, write so:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```